# Angular Performance and Apply Scope

Tags: angularjs

I was in the middle of the development of an Angular project, and had a breakpoint on a function called from one of the Angular templates, and discovered that the function is executed 14 times.

I checked the stack trace for each call, trying to discover why the function is  called this many times although it's not in an `ng-repeat` block or anything, and found out that it's mostly after xhr json calls.

I understand that angular applies scope.apply and digest after xhr.json calls, but some of those calls are not really relevant to the template involved and updates other DOM elements. What im having here i think is a template that is rendered 14 times with all the overhead with the compiling and DOM manipulation, which doesn't feel right, what are my options here?

[image]

**template:**

```
<ion-view title="Checkout">
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>

  <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <button  class="button button-icon icon ion-bag righthd-icon"></button>
    <button class="button button-icon icon ion-person righthd-icon"  ng-click="showUserOptions();"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>



  <ion-content class="has-header ourbgcol">

    <div>
        <div class="row responsive-sm ourprod">

            <div class="col col67 ourcolno">
                <ion-scroll class="product-details-images-container">
                <div class="lfgtp">
                  <div class="row ourrow">


                      <div class="col ourbxcol" ng-repeat="product in cart.products">
                        <img ng-src="{{product.img}}">
                        <div class="prdlistinfo">
                          <h3>{{product.name}}}</h3>
                          <h4>$ {{product.price}}</h4>
                        </div>
                      </div>  

                  </div>

                </div>
                </ion-scroll>
            </div>

            <div class="col col-33 checkoutrgt rghbg">
        <ion-scroll>        
        <div class="whitebg">
           <h3 class="totalhd">TOTAL ${{ cart.getTotal() }}</h3>
        </div>
    </ion-scroll>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**controller:**

```
angular.module('tailorapp.controllers').controller('ShoppingCtrl', 
            ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$http', '$log', '$ionicLoading', '$ionicPopup', '$ionicActionSheet', '$resource', 'localStorageService', 'settings', 'utils', 'api',
             function($scope, $stateParams, $http, $log , $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, $ionicActionSheet , $resource,localStorageService, settings, utils, api) {

    $log.info('Entering ShoppingCtrl scope');


    $scope.cart = utils.getCart();
...
```

**utils factory:**

```
.factory('utils', ['api', '$log', '$q',
function(api, $log, $q) {

    var utils = {};
    var currentUser;
    var cart = {
        products: new Array(),
        payment: 'cash',
        getTotal: function(){
            var total = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++){
                var product = this.products[i];
                total += (product.price * product.quantity);
            }
            $log.info("getTotal Executed");
            return total;
        }
    };
...
```

Comment: see what happens if you do `$scope.cartTotal=$scope.cart.getTotal()` and change function in html to a variable

Comment: its fired once, the controller function is executed once as usual, but if i rely on the function as in the post, is it normal that angular does 14 calls

Comment: not sure what `normal` is. Digest might still be running 14 times but removing function calls from markup is good practice to reduce overhead for sure. Also easier to test

Comment: It is normal in the sense that Angular evaluates expressions on every $apply. If the expression is a function call, it will be executed every time. Rerendering happens only when the expression result has changed.

Comment: @JessetheGame ah okay, so its not actually rendering 14 times, good to know, any callback to log rendering to see if angular is only rendering once?